# Python socketio client: recieve messages from a server (implementation inside a class)

Tags: python, server, socket.io, client

I can't recieve messages from my socketio server. I can connect to the server from client, send data and recive it on the server side but when i try to emit or send from the server side, the client does not get any responce.

My server side:

```
from aiohttp import web
import socketio
import json
from queue import Queue

from patterns.singleton import Singleton

class RemoteControl(metaclass=Singleton):
        
    sio = socketio.AsyncServer()
    app = web.Application()
    cio = socketio.Client()
    event_queue = None

    def __init__(self, q: Queue):
        self.event_queue = q
        
    def start(self):
        self.sio.on("message", self.my_event)
        self.sio.on("connect", self.connect)
        self.sio.on("disconnect", self.disconnect)
        self.sio.attach(self.app)
        web.run_app(self.app)
        
    def connect(self, sid, environ, auth):
        print('Connected: ', sid)
        self.event_queue.put({"action": "connect"})
        
    def disconnect(self, sid):
        print('Disconnected: ', sid)
        self.event_queue.put({"action": "disconnect"})
        
    def my_event(self, sid, data):
        self.event_queue.put(json.loads(data))

    def emit_event(self, data):
        print(data)
        self.sio.send("Hello from Car")
        self.sio.emit("responce", data)
        self.sio.emit("message", "Hello from Car")
```

My Client side:

```
import socketio
from queue import Queue
from webSocket.patterns.singleton import Singleton

CAR_CONTROLLER = "http://localhost:8080/"


class Websocket(metaclass=Singleton):
        
    sio = socketio.Client()
    event_queue = None
    connected = False

    def __init__(self, q: Queue):
        self.event_queue = q
        
    def start(self):
        self.sio.on("responce", self.responce)
        self.sio.on("message", self.my_event)
        self.sio.on("connect", self.connect)
        self.sio.on("disconnect", self.disconnect)
        try:
            self.sio.connect(CAR_CONTROLLER)
        except:
            self.event_queue.put('{"status": "Failed"}')
        
    def connect(self):
        self.connected = True
        self.event_queue.put('"status": "Connected"}')
        print("Connected!")
        
    def disconnect(self):
        self.connected = False
        self.event_queue.put('{"status": "Disconnected"}')
        
    def responce(self, data):
        print("Got a responce from car!")
        self.event_queue.put(data)
    
    def my_event(self, data):
        print('yay')
        print(data)
    
    def send_action(self, data):
        if (self.connected): self.sio.emit('message', data)
```

I suspect that the error comes from not constantly updating the self.sio.on("responce",...) but I can't figure it out.
Thanks for any help!